# Run react native app on Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode10

I get this error when i want to run my react native app hello world app on Xcode 10 (new beta version), can you help me?
The error :

> error: Build input file cannot be found:
>   '/Users/nic/Documents/X-Project/xapp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/libfishhook.a'

[Screen shot from my Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzpjh.png)

Comment: you can try this: https://medium.com/@rhdeck/running-react-native-with-xcode-10-beta-1-83c4334e7e0f Did not work for me though.

Answer (score 52):

[This](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19569#issuecomment-422691829) helped me:

> Remove and add again libfishhook.a from Xcode and the path issue will resolve.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow that actually worked. I've been doing this the long way for WAY too long.

Answer (score 21):

This issue is caught by the stricter [xcode 10 new build system](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10).

A temporary fix while react-native really fix the issue is to switch back to using the old build system

In **Xcode**, Select **File** -> **Project/Workspace Setting**. You will see a Build System option to select the **Legacy Build System** as shown below

[image: Legacy Build System option]

**Clear** your project and "Derived Data" **Build** and **Run** your project

**BONUS Point:** If you are using a CI/CD pipeline you can also add the xcodebuild argument `-UseNewBuildSystem='NO'` to the cli or via fastlane `xcargs: "-UseNewBuildSystem='NO'"`

Answer (score 10):

Manually copypasting libfishhook.a into the correct folder, as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19569#issuecomment-399652331), worked for me:

> For a solution, I copied the file from my ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libfishhook.a and pasted it into ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/ and got the build. I hope it helps.
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer helped me to solve problem. Just note that if it's tvOS, then the same action of removing and adding should be done of RCTWebSocket-tvOS.a